Sufficent conditions for real numbers to be lengths of sides of a quadrilateral
Looking at the triangle inequality, which states that positive numbers $a, b, c$ are lengths of a triangle if and only if the sum of each two is greater than the third. The immediate question is: can this be generalized for other polygons?
specifically for quadrilaterals, I am looking for similar conditions for positive numbers $a, b, c, d$ for them to be side lengths of a quadrilateral. Of course such a condition would be the existence of some $R>0$ such that $a, b, R$ and $d, c, R$ would be side lengths of a triangle, but I'm looking for something dependent purely on $a, b, c, d$.
Would really appricate some help. (Yes, I have noticed How long are the sides of a quadrilateral? but there is no sufficient answer there)

The necessary and sufficient conditions are that each side of your polygon is $\le$ the sum of the remaining sides. This works for all polygons. You can even guarantee convexity of the polygon.

Let $a\le b\le c\le d.$ The necessary condition is $d<a+b+c,$ i.e. the longest side is shorter than the sum of the lengths of other three sides. This condition is actually sufficient. Indeed, if $R\in (b-a,b+a),$ there is a triangle with sides $a,b$ and $R.$ Similarly if $R\in (d-c,d+c),$  there is a triangle with sides $c,d$ and $R.$ We can find a commonn value of $R$ iff $(b-a,b+a)\cap (d-c,d+c)\neq\emptyset.$ The last condition is equivalent to
two inequalities   $d+c>b-a$ and $ b+a>d-c.$ The first one is obvious as $d>b-a.$ The second one means that $d<a+b+c,$ the condition assumed at the begining of the answer.
Once we have two triangles with sides $a,b,R$ and $c,d,R$ we can glue them along the side $R,$ in order to get a quadrilatelar. If it is nonconvex we can apply a symmetry along the line connecting two nonconnected vertices.

What if it could be any quadrilateral, either convex or concave?

@Nate If we get a nonconvex quadrilateral we can mąkę it convex by applying symmetries.

One such inequality could be that $a+b+c>d$ for the sides of the quadrilateral:

As $R<a+b$ and $d<R+c$, then $d<R+c<a+b+c$.
The other if (if a,b,c,d are s.t $a+b+c>d$(or with another order), then they are sides of a quadrilateral) is proven in a similar fashion to how you would have proven for a triangle:

Fix side lengths a,b,c. Each length $d$ which will connect two sides must be with the property that $a+b+c>d$, so this would be a quadrilateral. If $a$ and $c$ couldn't be connected by $d$, then some other sides could be connected as some 3 sides have bigger sum then the length of the fourth side.

Is the generalization immediate for any polygon? (given positive numbers a_1,...,a_n such that the sum of each n-1 is greater than the remaining one, they are side lengths of a convex n-gon)
